# Split XML feed into two different PHP files

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML file:-

http://services.jupix.co.uk/api/get_properties.php?clientID=553a6644a7dc21df315c90e0140ad60d&passphrase=324dd464aa7ba96ad0e8ab6d8f423162

What I need to do is fetch this data and split it into two different PHP files.

Within `<property>` you will see:-

```
<department>Sales</department>
```

and

```
<department>Lettings</department>
```

These are the fields I need it splitting by.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Have a look at `SimpleXML`.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: "_split it into two different PHP files_" You need to split an XML file into to PHP files? What should those PHP files contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `DOMDocument` and XPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$properties = $xpath->evaluate('/properties/property[not(department="Sales")]');
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $property->parentNode->removeChild($property);
}
echo $dom->save('Sales.xml');
```

This will load the XML from the remote URL into a DOMDocument and remove all property items from properties that do not contain an element where department is "Sales". Then it saves the resulting document to the file sales.xml.

For Lettings, you just adapt the XPath and save file to say Lettings instead of Sales.

You can also do this with SimpleXml or XmlReader+XmlWriter or an XSL transformation easily. I will leave that for others to post though.